# 3ds max > collada > threejs animation error, "Scale out of bounds"

Tags: javascript, three.js, collada

I have exported a rigged, animated model to collada using the opencollada exporter from 3ds max. It loads fine and the animation runs, but every time the loop runs I get:

```
THREE.Animation.update: Warning! Scale out of bound ...
```

as in:

```
THREE.Animation.update: Warning! Scale out of bounds:-0.002944999956526251 on bone 0
```

**You can see this problem happening by opening the console** on the [page I've hosted](http://andrewray.me/stuff/wiggly-problem/). I have also put the source in a [github repo](https://github.com/DelvarWorld/wiggly-problem):

- [model file](https://github.com/DelvarWorld/wiggly-problem/blob/master/wiggly.DAE)
- [javascript](https://github.com/DelvarWorld/wiggly-problem/blob/master/index.html)

It seems to be happening from [this line](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/animation/Animation.js#L210) in the three source:

```
scale = ( currentTime - prevKey.time ) / ( nextKey.time - prevKey.time );
```

On the last frame of the animation, `nextKey` will be the first frame, and its time will be `0`. And `prevKey` will be the last frame, and in my case its time is `0.66666`. So `0 - 0.6666` is a negative number, and the "scale" it calculates is out of bounds.

Is this a bug in threejs, or a problem with how I've exported my models, or...? I don't see how this could should ever be working for looped keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an actual threejs bug as it happens with one of the examples. [Filed here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4218).